# hyperlink colour not changing?

Tags: html, css, text, colors, hyperlink

I am having trouble trying to get my link to stay white. 
This is the Head code.

```css
float1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 40px;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="float1">
  <font color="white"><a href="#" onclick="myfun();">Home</a></font>
</div>
```

Comment: font tag is deprecated and not supported in html5,use css instead

Answer (score 5):

Anchor tags by default have their own attributes if an `href` is present (to show the user that it is a link)

You need to add the color directly to the `a` tag:

```
#float1 a{
  color: #FFF;
}
```

or to all `a` tags if you prefer:

```
a{
   color: #FFF;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/khnym9sn/1/)

### OR

You can use `color: inherit` on the `a` which will then inherit it from its parent:

```
#float1 a{
  color: inherit;
}
```

[**ALT FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/khnym9sn/2/)

and remove the `<font></font>` tags as they are not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

The `<font>` tag is no longer supported.  But you can use `style=""` as an alternative.

```
<a style="color:white" href="#" onclick="myFun();">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the color white, even after the link has been visited, etc., the following apply depending on your preference for the cases for which the link text should be white:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link { color: white; }

/* visited link */
a:visited { color: white; }

/* mouse over link */
a:hover { color: white; }

/* selected link */
a:active { color: white; }
```

Or, if you do want all links on the page to be white, rather than just one particular link, for all of the above conditions, you could use just the following in a style section for the page or in a CSS file loaded for the webpage:

```
a { color: white; }
```

As mentioned, the font tag isn't what you should use to set the color of a hyperlink and should be removed. The [font tag has also been deprecated](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol6/beginner_no11.htm), though I don't know of any browser that does not still support it.

[Example](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/html/css/linkcolors.php)

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to apply a style to all of the possible conditions.  Applying it to the root (`a`) with no other conditions forces the link to be white always.

Comment: @DominatorX,  my intent was to show the person posing the question the conditions that can be controlled individually, which is why I noted "the following apply depending on your preference for the cases for which the link text should be white". I agree that what you posted is preferable if ProgramForFun indeed wants it always to be white. I didn't see your reply until after I added mine, but I thought I would leave it so that he could see that there are several conditions to which colors can be applied, not just the ones that apply before and after the link is visited.